# More than one password

Tags: javascript

Good Day.
I'm using a 'pasuser form' as a password protectant for a website page.
The script below only allows the use of ONE password and username.
Does anyone know how to change the script for multiple password/username use? Basically, I would prefer each user to have his unique password/username.
THANK YOU very much for your time and help.

```
function pasuser(form) {

if (form.id.value != "user") return alert("Invalid UserID");
if (form.pass.value != "pass") return alert("Invalid Password");
location = "http://tempuri.org/";
}
```

Comment: Are you serious? You are putting *passwords* in a client side script?

Comment: Looks like this is supposed to be a simple gatekeeper for your web page.  This is highly inadvisable since _anyone can read it_. Instead you could be using simple HTTP Basic Authentication to put a server-side password managed by your web server.

Comment: Please, learn something about AJAX and send the username and password to verify it on **server-side**, like this, you're showing to all users, what the right name and password is !

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Whatever it is, I suspect you're doing it the wrong way. Tip: User validation should not be purely client-side.

Comment: Checking passwords on a client-side script is not secure. Anyone could read the client-side code - browsers have a "view source" option. So they'd know which password to type. A secure approach needs to check the password against a store which is not accessible to the person typing the password. One way to do that is to  sending the user/password pair to a server, and then the server checks that pair  against its password database. This is called authentication. you might want to read up on it.

Comment: also, @ebby - pay no attention to all those people who are responding to your question non-constructively.

Comment: If you really want to do this, at least consider hashing the passwords. There are many Javascript Libraries that can do hashing, and many fall back to the browser's built-in implementation if available. This will not protect your protected resource (since the URL will be in plain text), but at least you won't leak users' passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Password protection in the client code is just foolish, but the principle might be useful for something else...

Put the user names and passwords in an array, and loop through the items:

```
var pass = [
  { user: 'ebby', pwd: 'john3' },
  { user: 'john', pwd: 'kate4' },
  { user: 'kate', pwd: 'ebby1' }
];
// look for a match
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
  if (form.id.value == pass[i].user && form.pass.value == pass[i].pwd) {
    found = true;
    break; // exit from loop
  }
}
// act on the result
if (found) {
  location = "http://tempuri.org/";
} else {
  alert('User name or password is wrong.');
}
```

Note: It's customary *not* to tell visitors if the user name is correct or not. The login process should not be possible to use to find out if a specific user exists or not. (Not that it matters when the user names and passwords are clearly visible in the page source, but anyway...)

Comment: This is inefficient.  (O(n))  Use a hash, which gets you near O(1):  `var pass={ebby:'john3', john:'kate3', ... };`, then you can just do `if (pass[user] === suppliedPassword) ...`.

Comment: @josh3736: Yes, it *can* be done more efficiently, but I hardly think that anyone would notice the difference. The code isn't inefficient until it *needs* to be more efficient.

Comment: The difference is [**very** noticeable](http://jsperf.com/hash-v-array) with just 100 items.

Comment: @josh3736: No, it's not. I just tried it with 10000 items, and I can hardly notice any delay at all.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I am right.  Your method is [provably](http://jsperf.com/hash-v-array) slower by an order of magnitude or more.  And the code is longer.  You can't seriously be arguing for a lose-lose proposition.

Comment: @josh3736: If you are going to log in several million times a second, then you would notive the difference. For any real world application, a few millionth of a second is not a delay that will ruin the user experience.

Comment: Uh guys, thanks for the prompt responses.
Nevertheless, some of your criticism regarding the security of this form was not necessary. Trust me; I'm fully aware of the 'risks' involved. I'm using it to access a page which does NOT contain any relatively private info.
Curious: if the JavaScript is on a separate file (kinda like the way css are created on a separate page) will viewers still be able to see the passwords/usernames info via View Source?

Comment: And thank you, @Guffa, the script works very well. Now I can keep visitors from accessing my clients' social security numbers. (JUST JOKING...!!!)

Comment: @ebby: If you include the script, it won't be directly visible when you view the source, but the URL of the script is, and in many browsers it's just one more click to get to the script source.

Comment: Thanks once again, @Guffa. In IE, the links were inactive, but in Firefox, they were, and as you said, one click and I was directed to the scripts. But as I said, even though I love the simplicity of the script et al, it's not being used to protect anything top secret. Another question: for 'top secret' files, I'm currently using HTaccess in conjunction with my host provider. I do not fancy the looks of the login form. Do you (anyone) have any alternative suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

set cookies and get them during authentication. The client can't view what is inside the cookies. But it will be better to use php.

Comment: the client  can't view cookies? I can! Using safari: preferences -> privacy -> cookies (and I don't recall what next. I believe it was something like 'manage cookies...').

Comment: @11684, perhaps he meant *sessions*?

Comment: sessions are cookies (albeit with a very short lifetime) and thus visible. @josh3736

Comment: Right, but the session's *data* is kept on the server; the client can't view what is inside the *session*.

Comment: seriously? I didn't know that.

Comment: Typically, the cookie the browser gets is just a key (usually GUID-like) to session data stored on the server.  On its own, it means nothing, so it doesn't matter that the end-user can see it.  If the user tries to modify the session key, they'll only end up with an invalid key; the server will simply create a new, empty session and assign a new key to the client.  The actual session data is never transmitted to the client.

Comment: Generally true but certainly not always - eg Code Igniter stores variables in the cookie by default. Also, that doesn't apply to cookies which are set by code intentionally to store details - like a username/password for a "Remember Me" button. Obviously this should be a token/similar but if the coder doesn't know that, huge security holes can appear